# Do While Menu Doesn't Print Correctly

Tags: java, printing

so I'm trying to have a do-while menu while I work with some methods the problem is my menu is printing on the part of the output. Let me explain, I choose the first option which prints every process, and after the first process is done it prints the menu instead of printing it when all seven (7) processes are done. Also, I have the same exact menu on another code I made and it works fine. Someone help, please. Thank You!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CristopherMunizProg1 extends Thread {
    
    static String completedProcesses[] = new String[9999];
    static int completed = 0;
    String processName;
    String myDependencies[];
    double budNeeded;//--------------------------------
    static double budget;//--------------------------------
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//--------------------------------
    static String[] names = {"P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7"};//--------------------------------

    public CristopherMunizProg1(String pname, String md[], double bN) {//--------------------------------
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        
        super();
        processName = pname;
        myDependencies = md;
        budNeeded = bN;//--------------------------------
        
    }
    
    public void run()
    {

        returnWhenDependenciesMet();
        System.out.printf(processName + " started with a required budget of $%,.2f %n", budNeeded);
        completed();
    }
   
    void returnWhenDependenciesMet()
    {
        boolean finished = false;
        if (myDependencies.length > 0)
        {
            while (!finished)
            {
                finished = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < myDependencies.length; i++)
                {
                    if (!isInFinished(myDependencies[i]))
                    {
                        finished = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
   
    boolean isInFinished(String p)
    {
        boolean finished = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < completedProcesses.length; i++)
        {
            if (p.equals(completedProcesses[i]))
            {
                finished = true;
            }
        }
        return finished;
    }
   
    synchronized void completed()
    {
        
        System.out.println(processName + " finished");
        budget = budget - budNeeded; //--------------------------------
        System.out.printf("\tAvailable Budget: $%,.2f %n", budget);//--------------------------------
        completed++;
        completedProcesses[completed - 1] = processName;
 
    }
    
    static void editName() {
        
        int optionName;
        String newName;
        System.out.println("Which Process Name Would You Like to Change? (1-7) ");
        optionName = input.nextInt();
        
        switch (optionName) {
        
        case 1: 
            
            System.out.println("Insert New Name for Process P1: ");
            newName = input.next();
            names[0] = newName;
            break;
            
        case 2: 
            
            System.out.println("Insert New Name for Process P2: ");
            newName = input.next();
            names[1] = newName;
            break;
            
        case 3: 
            
            System.out.println("Insert New Name for Process P3: ");
            newName = input.next();
            names[2] = newName;
            break;
            
        case 4: 
            
            System.out.println("Insert New Name for Process P4: ");
            newName = input.next();
            names[3] = newName;
            break;
            
        case 5: 
            
            System.out.println("Insert New Name for Process P5: ");
            newName = input.next();
            names[4] = newName;
            break;
        
        case 6: 
            
            System.out.println("Insert New Name for Process P6: ");
            newName = input.next();
            names[5] = newName;
            break;
        
        case 7: 
            
            System.out.println("Insert New Name for Process P7: ");
            newName = input.next();
            names[6] = newName;
            break;
        }
        
        
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        int option;
        
        do {
            
            //Menu
            System.out.print("\n      MENU     \n");
            System.out.print("\n1. Start Processes");
            System.out.print("\n2. Edit Process Name\n");
            System.out.print("3. Edit Process Dependencies\n");
            System.out.print("4. Edit Process Budget\n");
            System.out.print("5. Exit\n");
            System.out.print("<Selection> ");
         
            option = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
                     
            if (option==1) {
                
                System.out.print("Enter Available Budget: ");
                budget = input.nextDouble();
                input.nextLine();

                CristopherMunizProg1 p1 = new CristopherMunizProg1(names[0], new String[]{}, 10000);
                CristopherMunizProg1 p2 = new CristopherMunizProg1(names[1], new String[]{}, 20000);
                CristopherMunizProg1 p3 = new CristopherMunizProg1(names[2], new String[]{}, 30000);
                CristopherMunizProg1 p4 = new CristopherMunizProg1(names[3], new String[]{"P1", "P3"}, 40000);
                CristopherMunizProg1 p5 = new CristopherMunizProg1(names[4], new String[]{"P2", "P3"}, 50000);
                CristopherMunizProg1 p6 = new CristopherMunizProg1(names[5], new String[]{"P5"}, 60000);
                CristopherMunizProg1 p7 = new CristopherMunizProg1(names[6], new String[]{"P4", "P6"}, 70000);
                        p1.start();
                        p2.start();
                        p3.start();
                        p4.start();
                        p5.start();
                        p6.start();
                        p7.start();
            }
            
            if (option==2) {
                editName();

            }
            
            if (option==3) {
                //editDep();

            }
            
            if (option==4) {
                //editBudget();
    
            }
            
            if (option==5) {
                System.out.println("\nGoodbye!");
            }
        }while(option!=5);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: You will need to use `join` to wait for your Threads to finish before continuing the loop.

Comment: This example has to work like this I have another example where I have to implement join. What im trying to figure out why my output is:

MENU     

1. Start Processes
2. Edit Process Name
3. Edit Process Dependencies
4. Edit Process Budget
5. Exit
<Selection> 1
Enter Available Budget: 280000
P1 started with a required budget of $10,000.00 

      MENU     

1. Start Processes
2. Edit Process Name
3. Edit Process Dependencies
4. Edit Process Budget
5. Exit
<Selection> P3 started with a required budget of $30,000.00 
P2 started with a required budget of $20,000.00 
P2 fini